# How can i sort a laravel's elequent list by another ids

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have a challenge that if I want to sort the records when getting using Laravel's ORM based on a list of IDs, how should I do it?!!!!!!!

I mean :
Suppose we have a table called users, which contains 100 records and each record has a unique ID.
We also have an array of IDs.

```
$ids = [4,1,2,3]
```

Now I want to get the list of users, but only the users who are first in the ids array and secondly according to the same order as they are listed in this array.

```
User::whereIn('id' , $Ids)->sortBy('id',$ids)->get();
```

Can you think of a solution to do this?

```
User::whereIn('id' , $Ids)->sortBy('id',$ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collections `sortBy()` function can take a custom call back this way:

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $Ids)->get()
   ->sortBy(function($user, $key) use($ids) {
         return array_search($user->id, $ids);
      });
```

This will sort your collection according to the given array.

You can also reference [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby) for more information.

Note that the `sortBy()` function must act upon a collection, which means that the `get()` function must come before it.